# Programmatically convert multiple midi files to wave using timidity, ffmpeg, and bash

Tags: bash, file-io, scripting, ffmpeg, midi

I am trying to build a script to do as the title says, but I am somewhat unfamiliar with Bash and other online resources have only been so helpful.

```
#! /bin/bash
function inout  #Create Function inout
{
    output[0]=" " #Initialize variables
    input[0]=" "
    count=1
    while [ "$count" -lt  10 ]; #Start loop to get all filenames
    do
        echo "Grabbing filename"             #User feedback

        input=$(ls | grep 0$count | grep MID | sed 's/ /\\ /g') #Grab filename
        #Replace ' ' character with '\ '
        output=$(echo $input | tr 'MID' 'mp3')
        #set output filename
        echo $count #Output variables for testing
        echo $input
        echo $output
        let count+=1 #Increment counter

        echo "converting $input to $output." #User feedback
        foo="timidity $input -Ow -o - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k $output"
        echo $foo
        #The last two lines are for the purpose of testing the full output
        #I can get the program to run if I copy and paste the output from above
        #but if I run it directly with the script it fails

    done
}

inout
```

I am trying to figure out why I can't just run it from inside the script, and why I must copy/paste the output of $foo

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to tell from your code how the input files are named; I'll assume something like `song_02.MID`:

```
inout () {
    for input in song_*.MID; do
        output=${input%.MID}.mp3
        timidity "$input" -Ow -o - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "$output"
    done
}
```

They key is to define an appropriate pattern to match your input files, then iterate over the matching files with a `for` loop.

Also, your use of `tr` is incorrect: that call would replace any occurrence of `M`, `I`, or `D` with `m`, `p`, and `3`, respectively; it does not replace occurrences of the 3-character string `MID` with `mp3`.

Comment: The songs are titles 01 - Title.MID but your input line would probably work as just *.MID
This is so much cleaner than mine... Thank you! I will have to try it and see if it gives me the same guff.